# MPMoviePlayerControllers view inside UIView container

Tags: ios, uiview, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to show a movie that was captured with UIImagePickerController inside a generic UIView container but it's not working. The container view is visible but no video is shown in the container view.

I've put my code inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and this is what I've got so far. The capturing is working and I get a valid movie url but I'm not sure if I can/should just add the `moviePlayer.view` as a subview to the container and if it will be sized correctly. I was hoping the `scalingMode = .AspectFill` would take care of that.

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoContainer: UIView!

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        if let movieUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL {
            println("Movie url found: \(movieUrl)")
            let moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: movieUrl)
            moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
            moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            videoContainer.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
            moviePlayer.play()
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Documentation says :

> player's frame must match parent's

I can't see any line of code where you try to set the players view frame.
The scaling mode has nothing to do with the frame of the view. It is used to define how the video content is actually scaled inside the view

Comment: This did the trick! I also had to make the moviePlayer a class variable/parameter.